# Using Chrome debugger or Firefox dev tools, Can I get a log of all JavaScript functions entered & exited in a module?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

Using Chrome debugger or Firefox (or MSIE or MS-Edge), I would like to get a list of JavaScript functions entered and exited in one or more .JS modules that I specify.  I envision the list looking something like this:

```
Scoring.js : Pg03_ESI_initialize() : enter at 12:12:12.12345
NA_Library.js : initialize_NA() : enter at 12:12:12.12346
NA_Library.js : initialize_NA() : exit at 12:12:12.12347
Scoring.js : Pg03_ESI_initialize() : exit at 12:12:12.12349
```

Will any of the "popular" browser debug tools do this?  If not, is there a tool that will do it?  I'm debugging a webpage that's generated by a COTS product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here: https://raygun.com/learn/javascript-debugging-tips

the "monitor(function_name)" feature in Chrome will get me close enough.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.